# MySQL - How to select one user with max value per year

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-8.0

```
SELECT e.frist_name, SUM(e.prince), YEAR(e.hire_date) AS year FROM (
   SELECT * FROM employee WHERE termination IS NULL
) e
JOIN storage s ON e.id = s.eid GROUP BY e.id, e.hire_date;
```

After SQL query I have a table like this:

```
+--------------+---------------+------+
| e.first_name | SUM(e.prince) | year |
+--------------+---------------+------+
| Johnn        | 1450          | 2012 |
+--------------+---------------+------+
| Emma         | 1020          | 2013 |
+--------------+---------------+------+
| Gordon       | 340           | 2012 |
+--------------+---------------+------+
| Ave          | 600           | 2014 |
+--------------+---------------+------+
```

My desired result is something like this (only one user per year with max value of prince):

```
+--------------+---------------+------+
| e.first_name | SUM(e.prince) | year |
+--------------+---------------+------+
| Johnn        | 1450          | 2012 |
+--------------+---------------+------+
| Emma         | 1020          | 2013 |
+--------------+---------------+------+
| Ave          | 600           | 2014 |
+--------------+---------------+------+
```

Comment: The query is malformed. All columns not present in the `GROUP BY` clause should appear aggregated in the select list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER with a CTE

```
WITH CTE as (

    SELECT e.frist_name, SUM(e.prince) sum_ , YEAR(e.hire_date) AS year
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(e.hire_date) ORDER BY SUM(e.prince) DESC) rn   
    FROM (
       SELECT * FROM employee WHERE termination IS NULL
    ) e
    JOIN storage s ON e.id = s.eid 
    GROUP BY e.id,e.frist_name, YEAR(e.hire_date) )
    SELECT 
        frist_name, sum_, year
    FROM CTE
    WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: The non-aggregated columns not present in the `GROUP BY` clause produce unpredicatable results. This query may not be stable.

Comment: Why have the e subquery?

Comment: Probably to reduce the number of rows that must be joined

Answer (score 0):

SQL query that selects one user with the maximum value of prince per year, achieving your desired result:

```
SELECT e.first_name, SUM(e.prince), YEAR(e.hire_date) AS year
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM employee WHERE termination IS NULL
) e
JOIN storage s ON e.id = s.eid
GROUP BY year
HAVING SUM(e.prince) = (
    SELECT MAX(SUM(e.prince))
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM employee WHERE termination IS NULL
    ) e
    JOIN storage s ON e.id = s.eid
    GROUP BY YEAR(e.hire_date)
)
ORDER BY year;
```